# Will Java notice when a loop won't change anything, or should I use break statement?

Tags: java, jvm

I would like to determine whether some element of String-List has some other String as a substring. My approach was something like

```
//...
boolean found = false;
for (String elem : myList) {
    if (elem.contains(someString)) {
        found = true;
        break;  // <-- necessary?
    }
}
if (found) {
    // do something
}
```

My Question is: is the break statement useful here? Intuitively it seems like omitting it would cause unnecessary work, since I am only interested in finding out whether the string is contained as a substring at least once.

However, a clever compiler could notice that after `found` has been set to true, the state of the program cannot change any more. Will the Java compiler or the JVM recognize this?

Comment: Yes it is necessary. Why do you believe it wouldn't be?

Comment: Wouldn't it be great if we had cars that set the gear into reverse when we think it. Sadly we still have to do it ourselfs.

Comment: Not sure what is the "con" for using this approach? Longer code? (By a simple line)?

Comment: @WonderWorld It's not just that i _think_ it should break automatically, but it could in principle be determined that executing the rest of the loop cannot possibly change anything any longer. I didn't consider this extremely far-fetched

Comment: @peter_kalua In that case you should use a while loop. A for loop is not suited for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're absolutely right. The `break` statement doesn't change the semantics of the algorithm (nor the complexity) but avoids doing unnecessary work once an element has been found.

(The JVM will most likely *not* discover that `found` never changes from `true` to `false` and break the loop in advance.)

I usually put this type of snippet in a method though, and use `return` statements as follows:

```
for (String elem : myList)
    if (elem.contains(someString))
        return true;
return false;
```

---

If you happen to be using Java 8, there's a better way though:

```
boolean found = myList.stream().anyMatch(s -> s.contains(someString));
```

Comment: Can parallel version of stream,  use all cores or only available ones at that moment?

Comment: It depends on the underlying collection.

Answer (score 0):

Don't count on the compiler to break from the loop for you.

If you wish to avoid the break statement and still not do unnecessary work, you can re-write the loop this way :

```
boolean found = false;
for (int i = 0; i < myList.size() && !found; i++) {
    if (myList.get(i).contains(someString)) {
        found = true;
    }
}
if (found) {
    // do something
}
```

Or you can use a while loop.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a while instead of a for loop:

```
//...
boolean found = false;
int i = 0;
while (i < myList.size() && !found) {
  String elem = myList.get(i)
    if (elem.contains(someString)) {
        found = true;
    }
    i++;
}
if (found) {
    // do something
}
```